# Using filter function with multiple values for the same column in powerapps

Tags: datatable, powerapps

I am using microsoft powerApps for developing an application.
I have a table (x) with several columns, including a column (y).
Another table (z) with several columns also including a column (y).
I want to filter table (z) to get all rows that have values of column (y) that appear in table (x).
Any help how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The PowerApps LookUp function returns only a *single* record. OP states `...get all rows that have values of column (y) that appear in table (x)`.

This means they must use the Filter function. The PowerApps Filter returns a *table* of records.

To filter one table by another try:

- `Filter(z, y in x.y)` or  //returns a fuzzier match
- `Filter(z, y exactin x.y)`//returns a strict match

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely achieve this. You need to use [Lookup Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) available in PowerApps.

In addition here is nice [thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Lookup-a-value-from-one-connection-in-another/td-p/11298) you can look into

I have used lookup function in many of my apps created.